# Position of centroids after convolution

Tags: convolution, gaussian

One of the properties of convolution is that the centroids of the functions being convolved should add. See equation (18) of Wolfram Alpha's section on convolution [Convolution Properties](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html).

For example, if we have a Gaussian centered at t1=300, and we convolute it another Gaussian centered at t2=200, the resulting Gaussian peak after convolution is centered at 500. MATLAB works fine for that.

I was trying to convolute Gaussian functions, one centered at 0 (orange), and other one at 500 (blue), but the resulting function is not centered at 500 in MATLAB but appears much later (yellow). How can one circumvent this problem in MATLAB? I want to keep one Gaussian at 0. Thanks.

'''W=[0:1:2500]'; % bin numbers

g1= normpdf(W, 500, 100); % First Gaussian with unit area (x, mu, sigma)

g2= normpdf(W, 0, 100); % Second Gaussian with unit area (x, mu, sigma)

Convg1g2=conv(g1,g2)

plot ( g1)
hold on 
plot( g2)
hold on
plot(Convg1g2)'''

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is g1 is not a complete Gaussian pdf since you limited the range to not extend past 0.

The following will work for you:

```
W=[-2500:1:2500];
g1= normpdf(W, 500, 100);
g2= normpdf(W, 0, 100);  
ConvG1G2 = conv(g1,g2, "same");
plot(g1)
hold on
plot(g2)
plot(ConvG1G2)
```

Results in:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, so does the convolution of half g1 considers the centroid to be non-zero and that is why it is shifted forward? I am trying to understand the mathematical reason for the forward shift as shown in the original post.

Comment: Yes the centroid can no longer be at 0 if the other half is missing, right? (It is treating the negative side as 0 valued, and it is no longer a balanced function).

Comment: Right, thanks. It makes the connection now.